# Bus error when running Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am running emulator for Android 4.4. On running command `emulator -avd myAVD` it gives `Bus error` on console. How to fix it?

Comment: I'm running into this also.  I hadn't used my environment on Mac OS 10.6 in many months, tried opening it up, and haven't been able to open the emulator.  I was using standalone Eclipse with ADT installed separately, but also tried installing the ADT bundle and running it that way.  Both failed.

Comment: Running it through Android Studio works for some reason.  I also tried removing "~/.android", but that didn't seem to help anything.

Comment: Well, it worked in Android Studio until I updated the SDK.  :-)  I hate it when updating breaks something.

Comment: Found this:  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67036&q=bus%20error&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 3):

You want to be using `emulator64-arm`, it should be located in the tools folder, at the same place as the other emulator.

Comment: `emulator64-x86` precisely

Comment: @Volatil3 He was been on a Mac ;)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that I had to use `emulator64-x86` rather 32 bit default `emulator` file. I simply removed `emulator` file and renamed `emulator64-X86` as `emulator`. It worked then